# Getting a value from associative arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array..

```
$file=array(
    'uid' => '52',
    'guarantee_id' => '1116',
    'file_id' => '8',
    'file_category' => 'test',
    'meta' =>'{"name":"IMAG0161.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpzdiaXV","error":0,"size":1749244}',
    'FileStorage' => array()
)
```

and I am trying to extract the name using

```
$fileName = $file['meta'['name'];
```

which gives me a Illegal string offset 'name' error.

Comment: The value of `$file['meta']` is a string, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your meta is a `json`, so you should decode and then access whatever you need, not that I placed `true` as second parameter becuase i wanted to decode as an `associative array` instead of an `object`

```
$decoded = json_decode($file['meta'],true);
echo $decoded['name'];
//print IMAG0161.jpg
```

You can check a live demo [here](http://ideone.com/QyaSnO)

But you can easily access as an obect

```
$decoded = json_decode($file['meta']);
echo $decoded->name;
//print IMAG0161.jpg
```

You can check a live demo [here](http://ideone.com/Cw0lAA)

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$file['meta']` is a string, not an array. That means your approach to access the value does not work.

It *looks like* that meta value string is a json encoded object. If so you can decode it and then access the property "name" of the resulting object.

Take a look at this example:

```
<?php
$file = [
    'uid' => '52',
    'guarantee_id' => '1116',
    'file_id' => '8',
    'file_category' => 'test',
    'meta' =>'{"name":"IMAG0161.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpzdiaXV","error":0,"size":1749244}',
    'FileStorage' => []
];

$fileMeta = json_decode($file['meta']);
var_dump($fileMeta->name);
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(12) "IMAG0161.jpg"
```

---

In newer version of PHP you can simplify this: you do not have to store the decoded object in an explicit variable but can directly access the property:

```
json_decode($file['meta'])->name
```

The output of this obviously is the same as above.

Comment: For leaving a JSON obect as an object and not converting it to an array +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file=array(
    'uid' => '52',
    'guarantee_id' => '1116',
    'file_id' => '8',
    'file_category' => 'test',
    'meta' =>'{"name":"IMAG0161.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"\/tmp\/phpzdiaXV","error":0,"size":1749244}',
    'FileStorage' => array()
);
$meta=$file['meta'];
$json=json_decode($meta);
echo $json->name;   

?>
```